# make HTML button disappear on click, then reappear after X time?

Tags: javascript, html, button, time, hide

How do I make HTML button disappear on click, then reappear after 2 seconds?  I found some ways of doing this but I need it to work with the code I already have. How can I accomplish this?

```
<script language="JavaScript">

  function enableTorch(milliSeconds) {
    ipwajax('enabletorch');
    window.setTimeout("ipwajax('disabletorch');",milliSeconds);
  }

</script>
<input type="button" style="font: bold 20px Arial" onclick="enableTorch(1500);" value="LED ON">
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You may accept the most helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!--
$("p").hide()
Demonstrates the jQuery hide() method, hiding all <p> elements.
-->
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("button").hide();
    $("button").show(2000);/*2 sec time*/
  });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<button>Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

this one will hide the button and reshow in 2 sec

Comment: you can change the milliseconds at this line
`$("button").show(2000);`

Comment: But how do I do it together with the button I already have?  I posted the code I'm already using.  Please help.  Thanks

Comment: the js you have posted in your code can be replaced by another js or not?? or are you firm not to use another js?

Answer (score 1):

Check this

```
function enableTorch(milliSeconds) {
   ipwajax('enabletorch');
   document.getElementById('torch').style.display="none";
   setTimeout(function(){ipwajax('disabletorch');document.getElementById('torch').style.display='inline'}, milliSeconds);
  }


<input type="button" id = "torch" style="font: bold 20px Arial" onclick="enableTorch(1500);" value="LED ON">
```

Comment: Actually the button does work and diapers/appears fine but the LED does work now??

Comment: which led? Do you want to call function ipwajax()  as in your code. i will add that call to my code

Comment: Yes ipwajax('enabletorch') turns ON my android phone LED and then the LED also has to turn off automatically after 2 sec later ipwajax('disabletorch').  SO I'm trying to have the button disappear when LED turns ON and button to reaper after the LED automatically turned of after 2 or 3 seconds.

Comment: please check my modified code above. report if you have still problems

Comment: Yes both seem to work :-) you are the best man!  There is no way I'd ever figure this out on my own lol.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $(this).hide().show(2000);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/4eCrQ/

```
$('.first').on('click', function() {
    $('.second').hide();
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.second').show();
    }, 2000);
});
```